# Finding possible functions among the large number of "standard" common lisp functions?

Tags: common-lisp, libraries

Is there a way to discover common lisp function(s) by searching via description of what the desired function does rather than searching on function names? It is frustrating to only be able to lookup functions by name, when what is really needed is an ability to go from descriptive information to possible candidate functions! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

### Quicklisp-apropos

This new library was published a few days ago: https://github.com/mmontone/quicklisp-apropos It is part of [slime-star](https://github.com/mmontone/slime-star), regrouping several quality-of-life extensions for Slime.

To install, clone it somewhere, install the dependencies:

```
(ql:quickload '(:dexador :chipz :archive :montezuma :string-case))
```

and load the `quicklisp-apropos.lisp` file (C-c C-k, `load`…).

The system provides a few functions:

```
quicklisp-apropos:apropos                  -f------ 480.57
quicklisp-apropos:apropos-doc              -f------ 477.23
quicklisp-apropos:apropos-name             -f------ 477.00
quicklisp-apropos:apropos-class            -f------ 476.82
quicklisp-apropos:apropos-macro            -f------ 476.82
quicklisp-apropos:apropos-system           -f------ 476.68
quicklisp-apropos:apropos-package          -f------ 476.57
quicklisp-apropos:apropos-function         -f------ 476.48
quicklisp-apropos:apropos-variable         -f------ 476.48
quicklisp-apropos:apropos-generic-function -f------ 476.09
```

#### Search in the docstrings

```lisp
CL-USER> (quicklisp-apropos:apropos-doc "random")
50 results:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
system random in system NIL

Some simple random number generators.
random
======

ACM random number generator

random
======

ACM random number generator


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
generic-function FL.MATLISP:FILL-RANDOM! in system femlisp-matlisp

Fills X with random values (obtained by (random s)).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class CL-RRT:RRT-TREE-NODE in system cl-rrt

Node class of Random Tree.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function STDUTILS:SEED-RANDOM-GENERATOR in system stdutils

Evaluate a random number of items
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function STATISTICS:RANDOM-SEED in system scigraph

Return a random seed.

[…]
```

This searches on all Quicklisp's libraries (it downloads a cache of the index at first use).

### Ultralisp

Ultralisp also maintains an index, allowing to search by function names and documentation.

https://ultralisp.org/search/?query=random

---

My last idea would be an advanced Github code search.

> by searching via description of what the desired function does

if you are thinking search based on types or on example à la Smalltalk, I don't know such things.

Answer (score 0):

I have a library that does what you describe for either the standard library or for a selection of external libraries.

It is lib-helper, found here: https://github.com/albuspiroglu/cl-lib-helper
or quicklisp: (ql:quickload "lib-helper")

For example to find **any** (or replace the .* with the regexp of symbol name to filter further) symbol with the word "structure" in its **descriptions**:

```
;; to search only in standard library:
(std:find-syms '(".*" "structure"))
;; or
(std:find-syms ".* structure")

;; to search in custom libraries along with std:
(lib:find-syms '(".*" "structure"))
;;or
(lib:find-syms ".* structure")
```

I made the word **descriptions** bold above, to point out the detail that the documentation for objects are searched not only for variable namespace, but other namespaces as well. So find-syms will search the documentation created by:

```
(defun foo () 
  "this documentation string"
  (print "hello"))

;; or:
(defgeneric foo ()
  (:documentation "this string"))

;; or:
(defclass ()
 ((a :documentation "here as well")))

 (:documentation "or this class documentation"))

;; or
(defvar var1 nil "this documentation as well")

;; etc.
```

There are some other features in the library, such as helping with grouping functions in hierarchies, listing all functions within a hierarchy group, helping with drop-down search of functions, etc.

For a brief usage example screencast: https://youtu.be/NygQTvbkMjY

Edit1: I forgot to mention, that the search string is not only searched in descriptions, but also the "hierarchy-group" name that the symbol resides as well, helping with further narrowing down results.

Another helpful feature is, a class can be a last-element in the group hierarchy (instead of packages), and if that's the case it will have the list of its methods (the specific methods that act on that class) in its group, giving you the methods of the class, in a sense.